# Angular conditional class with pipe

Tags: angular

Trying to do a conditional class if progress == 100, but my syntax is not correct?

```
    [class.finalDone]="progress[file.name].progress | async == 100"
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Also, are you sure `progress[file.name].progress` will return a `Promise` or an `Observable` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `progress[file.name].progress` will return a `Promise` or an `Observable`. And then use it like this(wrap the expression till the `async` part in `()`):

```
[class.finalDone]="(progress[file.name].progress | async) === 100"
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-class-on-condition-with-async?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.